# Python Print statements don't work

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
a = input('enter a ') 
b = input('enter b ') 
c = input('enter c ')


def is_right_angled(a, b, c):
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])             #sort inputs smallest to largest
    pathag=(a * a + b * b - c * c) #< 0.1   #a ^2 + b ^2 - c ^2 should = 0 approx

    if pathag<0.1:                          # test "pathag" to to see if  close
     print ("This is a right triangle")
    else:                                   # if "pathag" not close, not "right"
     print ("This is NOT a right triangle")

    return abs(a * a + b * b - c * c) < 0.1
```

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: You've defined a function, but I don't see any calls to it.  What you posted should input 3 values, then fall through to the bottom and exit without doing anything else.

Comment: Also, just being defensive—there's likely a type error coming if you do call the function with `a`, `b`, and `c`. Reading them from `input` produces strings; you need to change them to a numeric type. You can do that by saying, for instance, `a, b, c = float(a), float(b), float(c)`.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy It depends on whether OP is using Python 2 vs. Python 3.  The `print` references suggest Python 3, but it could also be Python 2.

Comment: Valid point. If it is indeed Python 2, then the merit of `input` is an entirely different conversation. (In that case, I'd advocate `ast.literal_eval(raw_input())` over `input()` for safety.)

Comment: I am using Python 3.
I am also having type errors as described.
I have thought that my main problem was trying to call a variable from the  function to use in a print function.
Would I put "a, b, c = float(a), float(b), float(c)" up around line 4 ?
I'm sincerely grateful for the input !

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple issues specific to the print function not working (I think you might also want to revisit some of the logical assumptions driving your is_right_angled function.)

1) An input function creates a string variable. You will need to explicitly convert this to an int or float variable in order for your function to correctly work with these variables.

```
a = float(input('enter a '))
```

2) You are not actually calling the function in the above code. Be sure to call it or the code won't run. Add this to the end of your script:

```
is_right_angled(a, b, c)
```

Comment: The inputs are user based. I enter them to test the algorithm and see if the correct statement prints (if/when I learn how to make it work). I.E.: 3,4,5 should render "Is a right triangle"